# `rsync` ignores file containing ñ

Tags: rsync

I am using `rsync -avp` and one directory containing `ñ` is completely ignored. Is this a bug in rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option `--iconv=utf-8,utf-8`.  This requires version 3.0.0 or later.
Earlier versions of rsync can't handle such filenames: you'd need a workaround like hiding that directory in a .tar file.

Comment: Thank you very much. This option doesn’t seem to be available: `rsync: --iconv=utf-8,utf-8: unknown option`. I am using `rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29`.

Comment: Updated to `rsync  version 3.1.3  protocol version 31`. No error message but the file still gets ignored. UPDATE: false alarm. With 3.1.3 it also works without that iconv option.

Comment: (As you're new here...) it's customary to "accept" whichever answer worked best for you.  That guides other people, especially when there's a zillion answers.